# AWS Lambda Python function error 'Process exited before completing request'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a really simple script that I am using to enumerate the list of AMIs in my account and collect their IDS into a list.

```
import boto3

resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    amis = resource.images.all()
    ids = [ami.id for ami in amis]
```

When I run this piece, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX Process exited before completing request"
}
```

I can run other queries without a problem so permissions is not an issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Won't that list all AMIs you own plus all public AMIs? It probably is taking longer than the time you have allocated to your Lambda function.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big list and will take a long time to enumerate.  Also, you aren't actually returning the value once you compute it.

Comment: @MarkB ah! I didn't realise it would list all public AMIs - that makes sense.

Comment: @garnaat You are correct. I purposely removed that to isolate the problem call while troubleshooting.